# How to change the colour of primfaces Axis?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jqplot

How can I change the colour of primefaces Axis?
I don't see any default colour and I have no idea how to change it.

```
    public LineChartModel getLineChartModel() {
    LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
    model.addSeries(getData());;
    model.setTitle(televotingQuestion.getQuestion());
    model.setSeriesColors("black");
    Axis yAxis = model.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setTickInterval("1");
    yAxis.setLabel("Anzahl");
    Axis xAxis = model.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setMin(televotingQuestion.getMinValue());
    xAxis.setMax(televotingQuestion.getMaxValue());
    xAxis.setTickInterval("100");
    return model;
}
<p:chart id="votes" type="line" model="#{televotingNumericManagementBean.lineChartModel}" style="height:700px;"/>
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Better yet, use google and 'know' PF charts is based on jqplot

Comment: Then you also need to read the PF documentation and showcase about the 'extender' functionality... Please put some more effort in learning what you use... And putting your title in google already helps!!!

Comment: Any progress???

Comment: yes thank you, 
have done it with a extender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my extender:

```
<script>

        function colorAxes() {
            this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
                textColor : '#ffffff'
            };
            this.cfg.axes.yaxis.labelOptions  = {
                textColor : '#ffffff'
            };
            this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions = {
                textColor: '#ffffff'
            };
        }
    </script>
```

and that's how I used it in my bean:

```
  LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
    model.addSeries(getData());;
    model.setTitle(televotingQuestion.getQuestion());
    model.setSeriesColors("black");
    model.setExtender("colorAxes");
```